# How to get data from amoCRM through API?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I am trying to get data through API from amoCRM system but I am having some problems and I am really tired.

The url: https://alamiri.amocrm.ru/api/v4/contacts
This API should return contacts of users that contain (first name, email, number, ...).
When I copy and paste the above link in the browser, I get the data and everything works fine but when I try to get that data in Python it returns the following:

```
{'detail': 'Invalid user name or password',
 'status': 401,
 'title': 'Unauthorized',
 'type': 'https://httpstatus.es/401'
}
```

my code in python (Django framework):

```
import requests
import pprint


def get_contacts():
    url = "https://alamiri.amocrm.com/api/v4/contacts"
    api_key = "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"
    login = "my-email-that-I-used-to-create-account-on-amocrm"
    client_uuid = "e1899afa-85a8-45ca-93f9-7f4b26374a5d"
    client_secret = "jUlw4E6H417MVuzsujIW39GXXjpLjratAwOEiaqPr3KDBKYwc9ZQLXK2UlhMcsuu"
    headers = {
        'login': login,
        'client_uuid': client_uuid,
        'client_id': client_uuid,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}',
        'session_id': "a8f1uutp26uipj414pfudab8cv",
        'refresh_token': "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",
        "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImJkZDk0MTA1NTc5NWY0YzAwOTNmZDAwMmIxMDE1NDczZTZiN2ZjZDBlZGJlNWJlMWJjMjYzYTY2YTY2MGRlODA0OWQ5MjM5ZTE4ODY2MmQyIn0.eyJhdWQiOiI3YjQ5MGYxOC0yYmU1LTRhNTUtYTc0ZS0xOTYzYzk2NDFiOTgiLCJqdGkiOiJiZGQ5NDEwNTU3OTVmNGMwMDkzZmQwMDJiMTAxNTQ3M2U2YjdmY2QwZWRiZTViZTFiYzI2M2E2NmE2NjBkZTgwNDlkOTIzOWUxODg2NjJkMiIsImlhdCI6MTYzNzMzOTYzMywibmJmIjoxNjM3MzM5NjMzLCJleHAiOjE2MzczNDIwMzMsInN1YiI6Ijc2NDM4ODQiLCJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjpudWxsLCJzY29wZXMiOlsiY2hhdHMiLCJjcm0iLCJub3RpZmljYXRpb25zIiwidW5zb3J0ZWQiLCJtYWlsIl19.VEz7bIXpbsL-iMCz51UgW6JU1rySQTIXBLf_xPdBcmMpR3yIL8raUgCjEBJ05E05lhMsYxxwKEYg2yN468jkqfz5wTfmRdGs9ECiVatZ6oMEJYFUn7AF5JaP0fQw18raZdAo8CQJfZS86IuHEYpU2k-lW5LmDC2dIIyZYe4irnln0KRw5_mgci4JNPEyeqzYADI0deqX-rraXFjFm6UP4KkByfOrgfopyOV8cIBA_34i4CWewbVQLJF4-HWGuKvaOH5Erjh-GUNViyCCuH2Q4F7dI6gwhAd2z2lEbbTR_x4oyRx04QA1YOZjI64SJQAaaIYDFLphr7D4V59w44zG1g",
        "csrf_token": "def50200e00c062021bac6b78d51f10f45cc28add00268d9",
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    pprint.pprint(response.json())


get_contacts()
```

I am reading their documentation (amoCRM) and I tried a lot of things but none worked!

https://www.amocrm.com/developers/content/platform/abilities/

I followed their instructions how to work with their API:
https://nova-amocrm.notion.site/894277ffef5940e7a5daadd2abc746c8

But I am stuck and I don't know how to solve this problem!
Any help please?

If you don't know what is amoCRM, then

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should create an integration in your amoCRM account and use your google colab notebook link to redirection (or any other link).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyB7q.png)

Next, use the request to get ***refresh code*** and ***access token***:

```
data = {'client_id' : '3d31ef87-...',
        'client_secret' : 'xyEFPbRH5xw1...',
        'grant_type' : 'authorization_code', 
        'code' : 'def50200ec88c8fe724cfc58ebd7e19...',    
        'redirect_uri' : 'https://colab.research.google.com/drive/...'}

new_url = 'https://your_domain/oauth2/access_token'
request = requests.post(new_url, data=data)

request_dict = json.loads(request.text)
refresh_code = request_dict['refresh_token']
access_token = request_dict['access_token']
```

Next, define the request headers:

```
api_call_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
```

And after that you can get any information using filters:

```
api_statuses_response = requests.get('https://alamiri.amocrm.ru/api/v4/contacts?filter[id]={id}&filter[created_at][from]={from}&filter[created_at][to]={to}', headers=api_call_headers, verify=True)
print(api_statuses_response.json())
```